# Как сделать элемент над контентом, но чтобы не перехватывал события клика

Tags: javascript, css, события, mouse-event

Необходимо на всю страницу поставить эффект волны (такой как на Материалайзе).

**Суть эффект:** при клике на странице появляется кружочек, какой увеличивается и плавной исчезает через время.

**Суть проблемы:** из-за того, что элемент появляется он перекрывает кнопки для клика до тех пока не завершит свою анимацию. В некоторых местах это не удобно.

**Варианты решения:**
1. Не использовать эту анимацию или частично ограничить область использования;
2. С помощью какого-то способа сделать ее без "плоти", не кликабельной и соответственно, чтобы не перехватывала событие;
3. Ускорить анимацию.

Однако я надеюсь, что есть решение второго варианта.

Comment: Задать ей другой z-индекс, а контент сделать прозрачным?

Comment: реализовать обработку событий, чтобы при клике по анимационному блоку, перехват шел на кнопках, то есть, определять что в этой области был клик, и делегировать событие для кнопки, и тогда будет работать) Либо менять местоположение кнопок, чтобы не загромождало)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтобы мышь не реагировала на элемент для визуальных эффектов в css этого элемента можно прописать
pointer-events: none;

Comment: Забыл, Спасибо!